# Twitter for Zend Framework 1, REST API v1 no longer active

Tags: php, zend-framework, twitter

I have a website that was built in Zend Framework 1.
To get the latest tweets I used the following code:

```
$twitter_search = new Zend_Service_Twitter_Search('json');
$response = $twitter_search->search('from:username');
print_r($response);die;
```

I get the following result:

> Array ( [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [message] => The Twitter
>   REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1.
>   https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview. [code] => 64 ) ) )

Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: Solved by upgrading to Zend Framework 1.12 and using the following code:

```
$accessToken = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();
$accessToken->setToken('youraccesstoken');
$accessToken->setTokenSecret('yourtokensecret');

$twitter = new Zend_Service_Twitter(
               array(
                'username' => 'yourusername',
                'accessToken' => $accessToken,
                'oauthOptions' => array(
                    'consumerKey' => 'yourconsumerkey',
                    'consumerSecret' => 'yourconsumersecret'
                )
            )
        );

echo "<pre>";
$response = $twitter->statuses->userTimeline(array("count" => 5));
$tweets = $response->toValue();
print_r($tweets);
die;
```